# Get mobile operator in Windows Phone XAML app

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone, win-universal-app

My application responds to mobile operator information that I used to be able to get through 
    DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator;

It seems that this property is not available anymore for the new WP XAML and universal apps.

This information is critical since my application content depends on what mobile operator provider is the user connected to.

Is there some kind of a workaround for this?

Comment: have you tried reflection to try and obtain the property at runtime, not compile time?

Answer (score 0):

Since Universal apps run off the Windows RT platform the `DeviceNetworkInformation` class is not available.

To use the class `DeviceNetworkInformation` in your code you'll need to build a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.0/8.1 app instead.